# Laravel - how can I have a model available across each controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a laravel site that where every page is composed of two parts. I guess one way to abstract it would be to consider a multi-hosted blog, with the format *{url}*.blog.com/*{category}* (we can assume that the blog is further partitioned into categories, and each post has to belong to exactly one category).

At the moment, I have a route group that handles the *{url}* and *{category}* for me, which is fine, it means I have have my routes looking like this:

```
Route::get('/p/{post}', 'PostController@viewPost');
Route::get('/a/{author}', 'AuthorController@viewAuthor');
```

My problem is though, that every single method in my controller looks something like this:

```
function viewPost(Request $request, $url, $category, $post)
function viewAuthor(Request $request, $url, $category, $author)
```

Which means that I need to pass everything into my view, like so:

```
return view('posts/viewSingle', [
    'title' => $post->title,
    'url' => $url,
    'category' => $category,
    'post' => $post
]);
```

I'm seeing that there is a lot of duplicated code here, it would be great if I could somehow remove the *url* and *category* from each of my controller methods and still have access to it (I guess in the same way I can use Auth across my app).

The problem is, that this is my first attempt at using a PHP framework, and I'm not really away of the best practices. Based on my reading, I think I need two service providers, but I have no idea as to how to set them up.

I think my issues are further complicated in that I need to access the Request object in order to determine what *url* and what *category* I need to fetch from the database.

Comment: you can create common service file then call from any controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is called a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers).

```
// Using a Closure based composer
View::composer(['viewPost', 'viewAuthor'], function ($view) {
    $post = Post::find(app('request')->get('post_id'));

    $view->with('post', $post)
         ->with('category', $post->category);
});
```

The first parameter of the composer is a view name, an array of view names, or `'*'` for all views.

You can register view composers in a service provider.

Comment: Upvoted. @Garion, use this if you need to share the logic across views. If you actually do need the same stuff in different controllers, please edit the question and someone can help you write a custom service provider.

Comment: @Joel Hinz well I suppose I do need that functionally in every controller, and it restricts my database values (to ensure that only the relevant content is returned). I'm beginning to think now that I'm doing something wrong, and what I'm currently doing isn't standard practice?

Comment: Hard to say without having seen your application, but it does sound like there's a risk you're doing something you shouldn't, yeah...

Comment: @Garion perhaps look at root model binding to automatically load a model based on url segments.